# read and filter a .DAT file with different column amount in R

Tags: r, data.table, read.table

I have a `.dat` file with measurements. Some of these data are "broken". The rows where the broken data are should be skipped. The rows with the broken data have either a column amount over 6 or under 6. However I only need the rows with 6 columns.
So I tried to read the file `Daten2.DAT` in R with `data.table`. ([see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMCFh.png))
Does someone know how I can skip the rows not equal with a column amount of 6.

Comment: I've removed the Stata tag. I've nothing against Stata, quite the contrary, but tagging Stata and not even mentioning it, is just a distraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of reading the data with `data.table::fread`, read it in with `readLines`, split the lines by comma and then parse the lines.

```
ncols <- 6
y <- readLines(con = "Daten2.DAT")
y <- strsplit(y, ",")
y <- lapply(y, function(line_read){
  if(length(line_read) != ncols) NULL else line_read
})
y <- y[!sapply(y, is.null)]
df1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, y)
names(df1) <- paste0("Col", seq_len(ncols))
```

This assumes that there is no first line with column headers in the file.